# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 weird error on startup

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2010 and I've been using it for about 3 months now. Recently, It refused to start, giving me a "Operation could not be solved" error whenever I tried to do that. I tried reinstalling and now it's saying "Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies . Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004003(E_POINTER))"

Please help, I'm unable to open the program at all, and I can't program anything in windows until I get this fixed. I suspect it's something in the registry but I don't really know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suggestion  to narrow down your issue

1. Download [.NET Framework Verification Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx) to verify whether .NET Framework 4 is installed correctly on your machine or not.
2. If it verified successfully, could you please type `Devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs` to skip loading added to VSPackages. More [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms241276%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) about this.

Take care.

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was a broken .net framework install. Running a repair on .net framework 4.0 fixed it.